# electron-forge --template=typescript-webpack in vscode giving error Unable to resolve path to module './moduleName'

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, electron-forge

The App runs fine with `yarn start` so webpack is finding the module just fine. I cannot get vscode to see it though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)

```
yarn add --dev eslint-plugin-import @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

Also, on the dotfile `.eslintrc.js`, ensure you include on the root:

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "typescript": {},
  },
},
```